# Отправка email средствами php при изменении данных в базе, без захода на сайт

Tags: php

Всем добрый день
немного не понимаю как реализовать рассылку писем пользователям при изменении данных в базе.
имеется сервер, который общается с устройством. данные об устройстве заносятся в базу. также имеется веб-интерфейс.

При изменении некоторых параметров (а точнее при длительном неизменении) нужно уведомить об этом соответсвующих пользоваталей. Но часто заходить в веб-интерфейс не получается, нужно чтобы система работала автономно

Собственно, как реализовать отправку писем не заходя на сайт?

нагуглил некий cron и зацикленный скрипт - это единственное решение?

Comment: переменная, которая будет содержать время последнего входа на сайт. И потом каждый день в определенное время сравнивать эту переменную. Если в какой-то день разница текущего времени и значения переменной привысят определенную цифру (например 3 дня) то отсылайте сообщение

Comment: в этом и вопрос, как произвести проверку, не запуская браузер

Comment: Например есть [такой сайтик](http://cronjob.ru/)

Comment: Так же вариант - настройка cron`a

Comment: `CRON` и `Daemon` - немного разные вещи, условно их разделяют, хотя крон является 100% реализацией демона. `CRON` вполне распространен, управлять им легко, так что я советую вам посмотреть в его сторону, он у вас 100% имеется.

Answer (score 0):

Да, cron, в данном случае - наилучшее решение.